# remove custom master page for modal popup

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-masterpage, custom-web-parts

I am using visual studio 2013 for custom webparts and I have a page(call it X.aspx) which has a link that opens a modal popup(body only page) and has a custom webpart in it and it is referencing site custom master page(for X.aspx one)

How can I avoid the custom master page and apply the seattle master page.

I am trying to avoid header, footer from custom master page.

Thanks,
Michaeld

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail?  How are you creating and referencing the modal?  As much detail as you can add will help to find you an answer.

Comment: @Shelby, I edited the question again for clarity .

Answer (score 2):

When you call the page you can use the `IsDlg=1` query string.  That may be enough for what you need, but it depends on how the custom page was implemented and if it's still make's use of the notdlg classes.

Here is a potential answer on Stack Exchange regarding dynmaicly setting asp.net masterpages:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581950/can-i-change-a-nested-master-pages-master-dynamically

```
Just tested this and it works from the PreInit of the Page that is using the nested MasterPage.
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Master.MasterPageFile = "/Site2.Master";
}
```

Another method that may be possible is creating your own pagelayout class, that is used in publishing pages.  If you look at the pages they don't seem to reference a master page directly, but pagelayout assembly.

Back to the notdlg classes, you could modify the masterpage and add in the MS class to the sections you want to hide and then just utilize the query string method.

To clarify there are actually two different classes depending on version

```
s4-notdlg - SP 2010
ms-dialogHidden - SP 2013
```